# Filtering noise from FFT, where noise is known to be shifted delta function

Tags: fft, noise, filtering

I have an input sequence $x=\{x_1, x_2 , ... x_n\}$ of reals, where $n=2^m$ for some $m$. I wish to calculate FFT of $x$.

$X=FFT(x)$

However, before  I calculate the FFT, the signal $x$ gets corrupted with noise $\eta$, so $\hat{x}=x+\eta$, and calculated FFT, $\hat{X}$ is FFT of $\hat{x}$, rather than $x$.

$\hat{X}=FFT(\hat{x})$

I wish to  recover actual or approximate FFT $X$ from $\hat{X}$ under following assumption:

1. $x$ is band limited signal; FFT spectrum dies down quickly.
2. The noise $\eta$ is a shifted delta function, with unknown shift and magnitude, i.e. $\eta(n)= R\delta (n-l)$, where $R,\ l$ are real and integer respectively.

How will I do it in a compute efficient way?

Comment: Is the band limit of $x$ low enough that some upper part of the spectrum only comes from the noise?

Comment: It's fair to assume that.

Answer (score 1):

High-pass filter the input with a zero-phase filter to eliminate the signal of interest, leaving only the high-passed noise. If the signal is periodic, you can do this in the frequency domain and convert back to time domain by IFFT. Find the time of the peak and deduce the magnitude of the unfiltered delta function from the magnitude of the filtered delta function (the peak value or [root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square)). Knowing the delay and magnitude, subtract the noise from the original input signal. Do FFT.

Answer (score 1):

There is more effective method for decision of  your problem. Try to use some non-linear filter in **time domain** before calculating of FFT. Median filter is simple and effective filter for reducing impulse noise ([Median_filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter)). You can use simplest version with size of 3.

**UPDATE**

It is answer to comment of zimbra314.

Strange constraint. It is easy to reduce impulse noise in time-domain, but not in frequency-domain. But, is it your homework? If so I can give you a hint. Please do FFT of delta function. See to amplitude and phase of this spectrum. The amplitude spectrum of delta function has very simple form and there are a lot of high-frequency components. Your signal is band-limited, so there are not any high-frequency components. So you can easy estimate a amplitude spectrum of your noise . As you know, FFT of sum of 2 function ($x+\eta$) is sum of FFT of this signals. So you can calculate amplitude of $X$ very easy by subtraction amplitude spectrum of noise from $\hat{X}$

Is it possible to estimate phase spectrum of delta function. See phase for different values of shift of delta function... I think you will find method of estimation of phase spectrum yourself.

**UPDATE 2**

Spectrum of delta function ($\eta(n)= R\delta (n-l)$) is quite simple and well known. Spectrum of your band limiting signal $x$ does not have any high-frequency components. So high frequency components of spectrum of ($x+\eta$) equals to high frequency components spectrum of $\eta$. Algorithm is:

1. calculate $\hat{X}=FFT(\hat{x})$
2. estimate parameters of spectrum delta function $\eta$ from high-frequency part of  $\hat{X}$
3. calculate estimating spectrum $\Theta$ by using parameters from step 2
4. calculate estimation of ${X}=\hat{X} - \Theta$

Comment: I have additional constraint that I can only do any operation in calculated fft, what do I do in this case?

Comment: It's not homework problem.

Comment: @zimbra314, Sorry. Do you have questions about my hint?

Comment: Well, ultimately it boils down to how to calculate fft of signal that consists of single complex exponential. And it seems the best way to do it is doing an fft, but doing so is inefficient as it takes same time as doing original fft. I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: @zimbra314, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. Question: How do I effectively do step-2, is there a known algorithm, whose complexity is linear in number of smaples?

Comment: @zimbra314. You can easy estimate parameters in linear time. Amplitude  is constant, phase is linear function (do not forget about folding in 2*pi period). Standart least squares methods for linear regression are very effective.

Comment: @zimbra314. Please read help of SE about asking of question - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error. Citation - "Check to make sure that your question has the following: ... Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem."

Comment: DSP is not my domain; The problem with doing research on something that is not your domain, is that you do not know correct terminology, thus most of the research becomes futile. However, for this problem I came upto converting problem into,  how to find  frequency of a single complex sinusoid, this is where I am stuck. So your solution is basically square one to me. However, I pose the problem as generic as possible so as not to modulate your thinking with my own, usually if my approach is wrong then, all answer I get is delta improvement over already wrong solution.

Comment: @zimbra314 Now I do not understand connection of your problem with "how to find frequency of a single complex sinusoid". May be... Do not know... But I think start point for beginner in DSP will be learning  of DFT of delta function. You can do it analytically (see  definition of DFT) or numerical by FFT (matlab/octave, python and etc).